# How to get certain data from a page to be recorded into a file using php?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, extract

I am using Facebook Graph API to get the reach of a certain post in a webpage

and it returns a page with this content:

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "id":"129788793265_10154069879148266/insights/post_impressions_unique/lifetime",
         "name": "post_impressions_unique",
         "period": "lifetime",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": 1627
            }
         ],
         "title": "Lifetime Post Total Reach",
         "description": "Lifetime: The total number of people your Page post was served to. (Unique Users)"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/<postID>/insights/post_impressions_unique/lifetime?access_token=xxxx",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/<postID>/insights/post_impressions_unique/lifetime?access_token=xxxx"
   }
}
```

I want to extract just the "value" 1627 from the page into a file every 10 mins.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The response you get from the API is [JSON](http://json.org/). So in PHP you need a [**json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to extract the required data.

For running the script every 10 minutes, you can [setup a cron](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) or you could try *Poor mans cron*. Here is a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857770/4003801).